# Adding object in array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am saving array in firestore document. I want to add another object to it which I am unable to while saving for example `value:m1 , status:open`

This is `home.html` code, please see `[(ngModel)]="words2[in].value"`

If I try to do `[(ngModel)]="words2[in].value",open.status`, it gives error

```
    <form #formRef="ngForm">
        <div *ngFor="let word2 of words2; let in=index" class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="milestones">
                <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Milestone" [(ngModel)]="words2[in].value" name="name{{in}}" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" required (ionChange)="chng(words2[in].value)"></ion-input>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <button [disabled]="!formRef.form.valid" (click)="add()">Add Milestone +</button>
      </form>
      <br />
      <br />

  <ion-button (click)="CreateNewProject()">
    <ion-icon size="small" slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
    &nbsp;Create new Project
  </ion-button>
```

In `home.ts` when I am creating creating record, I am simply passing the `this.word2`, see code below:

```
  CreateNewProject(){
    console.log(this.words2);
    let record = {};
    record['name'] = this.val1;
    record['desc'] = this.val2;
    record['milestone'] = this.words2;
   ...
```

This is how it is getting saved in Firestore:

[image]

Comment: I have applied the usual question fixes: quote blocks that are not quotes, and fixing the case of the personal pronoun "I". You are still not making sufficient effort with your questions, which creates a need for volunteers to clean up after you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
record:any = [];    
CreateNewProject(){
        record.push({
         name:this.val1,
         desc:this.val,
         milestone:this.words
       });
   }
```

And you can access the value by 
eg: `record[0].name;`

Comment: you misunderstood, i need to save object in milestone array, nothing related to name or description

Comment: for that try 
record['milestone'] = []; //initilize as array
record['milestone'].push(this.words2); //push object into that array

Comment: :)   dude milestone array is saved from this code `[(ngModel)]="words2[in].value"` , see pic in [0] `value:m1` is saved, i want to save, `status:open` along, how do i do that ? i need to write something here - `[(ngModel)]="words2[in].value"` hope you get it